# Combining contextAPI, useState, and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, promise, use-effect, use-state, react-context

I'm trying to practice my knowledge of React by testing out a few things. Via useEffect I'm calling a method in contextAPI which calls an API to get some random data. My goal is to get the response and send this back to the Home component and set the state. This is turn should update the component and render the list of data in the home component. What I'm getting is something a little different. The promise I get is indeed processed but only in my context. This array isn't sent to the component before before rendering. I tried to add the state "names" as a second parameter in useEffect but this causes an endless loop. Moreover, as per [this resource](https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-hook-examples/) I tried to force useEffect to watch the setter but this also didn't work.

[Here is my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/contextapi-hooks-wjvuk?file=/src/App.js):
Would someone please tell me what is incorrect with my approach?

On a side note, contextAPI seems to be going crazy with re-renders and I'm getting way more prints to the console than I had anticipated. Would someone be able to explain this?

Comment: [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/contextapi-hooks-forked-gkq77?file=/src/components/pages/Home.js) _(changes made in `Home` component and the context file)_. Problem in your code is that, instead of passing the actual data to `setNames`, you are passing a promise to the `setNames` function.

Comment: Hi Yousaf, thanks for the pointer. This.. seams like an obvious solution. Nonetheless, thanks!